# Passing the input of HTML UI elements into a page request

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bunch of filters done in HTML (and bootstrap, I believe)

```
<li>
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Condition <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">New</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Used</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Next to them I have an "Update button". I would like that when a filter is used, the option that you pick is somehow saved and sent along the next time you press Update. For example, in the form of a GET parameter &condition=new.

How can I do this?

Comment: It's called a 'form' and exists since the dawn of time. Use a `<form>`, a `<select>` and a `<input type="submit">` and you're done. After that, you could optionally add some Javascript smart stuff to refresh the page using AJAX using the information you already have in your form, but now you're writing everything from scratch including your form and your controls. Why make it so hard?

Comment: @GolezTrol Who said I wanted to make it hard? I'd like this to be as simple as possible: the parameters from the dropdown have to be passed as url parameters. How is this hard? You're the one talking about ajax, not me. If you can't reply in a polite way, don't reply at all ok? Thank you.

Comment: I don't see how I am impolite. I just gave a suggestion. But if you find it impolite, I'll refrain from elaborating my suggestion in an actual answer. Good luck.